# JavaScript Date object always printed in America/New_York timezone?

Tags: java, javascript, timezone, jackson, jodatime

I have a time-stamp in milliseconds ([Unix time / time from Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) sent from my server, which uses Joda-time and always the constant timezone "**America/New_York**".  On my client, I also want to guarantee time is displayed according to the **America/New_York** timezone.  I've relied on the [MDN Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), and have decided it's easiest to instantiate my Date objects using the new Date(*milliseconds*) constructor.

***Now the hard part:***  I want to be able to print the time for clients that are using my site outside the America/New_York timezone.  I know I can [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) from a `Date object`, so now I'm considering performing arithmetic on that object based on the offset and relying on the server to tell me if I'm in DST or not.  Using [this method from the Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#isStandardOffset%28long%29).

I'd like a solution that works in IE8 as well as the modern browsers.  Any thoughts?  Are there any small utilities that already accomplish this in a standard way?

```
// dateTimeAsString is sent from the server (via JSON) as a String
// dateTimeAsString example: "1311387300000"
var dateTimeAsInt = parseInt(dateTimeAsString,10);
var dateTimeInNY = new Date(dateTimeAsInt);

// My current offset is 240
var nyOffset = dateTimeInNY.getTimezoneOffset();

// Somewhere out west
var dateTimeInTexas = new Date(dateTimeAsInt);


var isDST = false; // sent from server


// What I want to do, this is not legal JavaScript
dateTimeInTexas.printWithOffset(isDST,nyOffset);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't have timezone information. They able to display only in UTC and in current OS timezone. Even it's not guaranteed that a client has any knowledge about "America/New_York" timezone (e.g. a poor, weak mobile device).

If you want display dates in a particular timezone, the easiest way it convert it to a formatted string and transfer it as a string, not milliseconds.

If you need to do some calendar calculations on the client side, you are unlucky... You have to do it manually.

BTW, you cannot use timezoneOffset as is, because it could be different for particular dates, DST is important too.

So, first of all. What do you want to do with dates on the client side?

Comment: Hi kan, thanks for the answering.  The `Date` object on the client-side is going to be used for a number of things, but one of my requirements is that I can pass it to a [jQuery plugin I'm using](http://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) which expects a regular `Date` object.  I could potentially change the server so that it passes day, month, year, hour, minute, second - I just think that's overkill.  Is passing individual fields the only way I can guaruntee that I make a `Date` object with the display I want?  i.e. I can display 2011-09-22 12:48PM and hard code timezone info

Comment: In this case you should transfer date parts (ISO-8601 is good choice), then use date picker so it doesn't matter which timezone is used on the client side, then transfer picked string as is and parse it on the server side with the New_York timezone. And explicitly say to users that all dates are in this timezone.

Comment: I remember I've investigated GWT source code for their tz implementation - wow, that's a lot! Also, it does include quite large tz info table.

Comment: Yes, I'll be explicitly telling users that all values are in `America/New_York` timezone (it's actually a customer requirement).  My concern was simply that I don't want to write all those extra lines to serialize/deserialize fields in a granular way.  I'm thinking the solution to this may just be to send separate fields and to use the `new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])` constructor to create my object.

Comment: I recommend you on server side to use ISO-8601 formatter to string (the jodatime has one). On the client side you have to make converters from the string to the js Date object and back (maybe there is some code already somewhere in the jQuery, I have no idea). Anyway, the ISO format is very easy to parse and to format.

Comment: Just to clarify. You cannot use milliseconds on client side, because it's necessary to able convert string like "22/09/2011 18:18:30" into unix-time milliseconds, but the client side may not have the New_York timezone information, so it's impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment.  I know that the client side may not have the `New_York` timezone, that's what I'm trying to mitigate.  The display format, after instantiating the `Date` object on the client-side is less important as I can simply call `dateObj.getHours()` , `dateObj.getMinutes()` , `dateObj.getSeconds()`, etc. to render the display.  It's just important to me that I have a `Date` instance where `America/New_York` is assumed.

Comment: You cannot assume a Date instance to have New_York, because a client could not have the timezone info. Moreover, actually you cannot use the Date object at all. E.g. if a client has the London timezone and he tries to choose the 02:30am, but on this date in London there is daylight saving time switch day, but not in New York. He will not able to select such time because it doesn't exist on that date. However usually it's very improbable situation (I hope for you too), so nobody cares and use the Date object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3704/discussion-between-kan-and-brian-l)